How to efficiently select two counts from a table
I have a table, and I want to efficiently to get total count of tuples in the table, and total count of tuples with a filter.
If I use two SQL statements, then that's easy:
select count(1) from mytbl where enabled=true;
select count(1) from mytbl where enabled=true and age=10;

I am just thinking if there is a more efficiently way to get the two counts, for example combine the two statements into one, as the second query is based on the first.
My db is postgres.
Try the two queries solution, but I want a more efficient solution.

Sidenote: A column "age" with datatype int is often incorrect. Mostly the name is wrong or if it is really an age, we should rather use a datetime column.

Use a FILTER clause:
SELECT count(*) AS enabled_count,
       count(*) FILTER (WHERE age = 10) AS enabled_age10_count
FROM mytbl
WHERE enabled;

Note that count(1) performs worse than count(*).
